# lots of errors in dns log

Tags: domain-name-system

I've got lots of errors in my DNS log:

```
Mar 18 17:26:38 server named[3240]: validating @0x2aacec5b18e0: com NS: got insecure response; parent indicates it should be secure
Mar 18 17:26:38 server named[3240]: error (insecurity proof failed) resolving 'com/NS/IN': 2001:470:20::2#53
Mar 18 17:26:38 server named[3240]: validating @0x2aace80c3cc0: com NS: got insecure response; parent indicates it should be secure
Mar 18 17:26:38 server named[3240]: error (insecurity proof failed) resolving 'com/NS/IN': 74.82.42.42#53
Mar 18 17:26:38 server named[3240]: error (chase DS servers) resolving 'addthisedge.com/DS/IN': 74.82.42.42#53
Mar 18 17:26:38 server named[3240]: validating @0x2aacec5cba60: com NS: got insecure response; parent indicates it should be secure
Mar 18 17:26:38 server named[3240]: error (insecurity proof failed) resolving 'com/NS/IN': 2001:470:20::2#53
Mar 18 17:26:38 server named[3240]: validating @0x2aace80c3cc0: com NS: got insecure response; parent indicates it should be secure
Mar 18 17:26:38 server named[3240]: error (insecurity proof failed) resolving 'com/NS/IN': 74.82.42.42#53
```

They do not affect my DNS operation, what does them mean? I've set up 2 forwarders, do they matter?

Answer (score 1):

They're messages relating to DNSSEC, and the fact that your resolver is trying to work with it but being stymied.  Read the manual for your version of BIND to find out more, and for information on how to configure it correctly (or disable it, if necessary).

Comment: I've disabled auto validation and the errors now disappeared